# Patch & Update requests to remarketingAudiences returning 500 error

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to patch or update Remarketing Audiences using the [Google Analytics Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/remarketingAudience/update). However, when I do so, I keep getting a 500 error. Here is an example of the audience I'm trying to patch/update:

```
{u'linkedAdAccounts': [{u'linkedAccountId': u'679-395-yyyy', u'type': u'ADWORDS_LINKS'}], u'linkedViews': [xyz], u'name': u'Test - 123', u'audienceType': u'SIMPLE', u'audienceDefinition': {u'includeConditions': {u'daysToLookBack': 30, u'isSmartList': False, u'segment': u'users::condition::ga:browser==Safari', u'membershipDurationDays': 30}}}
```

The problem does not occur for inserting, however. Any ideas on what might be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 500 error might result during heavy load or for larger more complex requests. Try to use a shorter time period or reduce the complexity of the request, for example by removing the segment and check if the error persists.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'll try and simplify the request, except it's pretty simple as is. And it is based on the example provided in the API.

Comment: Ok, let me know.

Comment: Thanks. So, I simplified the request to only include the name, linkedAdAccounts, and the segment and I'm no longer receiving the 500 error. I suppose the default example is "too complex."